SwiftUI assistance with making the background a tappable object on Apple Watch
I currently have a small bit of code set up where I'm looking to be able to tap the button and perform an action while tapping the background of the button performs a different action. I seem to have something set up although the button's area seems to be larger than the actual visible button - therefore when I click the area just outside of the button the button's actions are still performed. I think it's due to the VStack but not sure how to change this
When I make the button much smaller the background area becomes bigger and therefore easier to tap although when analysing I still found that the button's tappable area to be larger than the actual button. I've copied the code for the button structure and the button in question. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm relatively new to SwiftUI
// Set the properties of the stop button
struct StopButton1: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .contentShape(Circle())
            .frame(maxWidth: 150, maxHeight: 150)
            .padding(10)
            .controlSize(.large)
            .background(Color(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0))
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .semibold))
    }
}

 if showConfirmation == true{
                
                ZStack(alignment: .center){
                    Button(action: {
                        //  showConfirmation.toggle()
                        
                        print("NEW VIEW")
                    }) {
                        
                        VStack(){
                            Text("END").font(.system(size: 40, weight: .semibold))
                            Text("2nd Half").font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    }.buttonStyle(StopButton1())
                      // .ignoresSafeArea()
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.3))//.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("OLD VIEW")
                    }
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }

I've also commented out the ignore safe area as that move the button to the top of the Apple Watch screen, any assistance to stop it from doing that would be appreciated!
